# Evaluate the sum $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$

Tags: combinatorics

Can someone be kind to help me to verify the sum $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$, using generating functions?

My result is: $4{n+1\choose 2} + 4{n+2\choose 3} +{n+4 \choose 5} + 6{n+2\choose 3} + 6{n+1\choose 2} + 11{n+1 \choose 2} - 6{n+1 \choose 2}$

Comment: The sum of **what**?

Comment: Note: to get ${a\choose b}$, use the command **{a\choose b}**.

Comment: If you mean $\sum_4^n k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)$, it is conceivable that your expression, when clarified, will turn out to be correct. But for sure there is a far simpler expression, involving a single binomial coefficient.

Comment: @vadim123: Or `\binom{n}{b}`.

Comment: @André: Or no binomial coefficient at all: $\frac{(n+1)^{\underline5}}5$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I am interested: how would you write the expression more simply?

Comment: Well, I really don't know what OP means by sum. But if it is the sum I gave in the comment above, the terms are $4!\binom{k}{4}$, and $\sum_4^n \binom{k}{4}=\binom{n+1}{5}$.

Comment: where is the sum??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean to evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^n k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)$, the falling factorial approach hinted above - i.e. using $\Delta(N^{\underline{m}}) = m N^{\underline{m-1}}$ seems nice to tackle this problem.

If you must use generating functions, note the ogf of $P(n)=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)$ is obtained by the operation $P(xD) \dfrac1{1-x}$, where $D$ stands for differentiation.

Then to sum, we need to divide further by $(1-x)$. From there you should be able to find the coefficient of $x^n$.